# Condenser for my heatpump is wired with 3 capacitors, two of which go to the fan motor

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

I have a heatpump that has been extremely noisy and isn't spinning, so I'm going to replace that, but looking at the wiring did I discover an odd one. The condenser fan is a 1075RPM 1/5HP 1.3A 5MFD 4 wire.... it's wired into a 5 MFD capacitor on two wires (yep normal like my others), one black wire into one contactor and the other yellow wire goes to a 330VAC 35MFD capacitor (yellow). Why on earth would the fan be wired into a 2nd capacitor?

There is a 3rd capacitor, which is a 124-149MDF 330V start capacitor. I'm replacing the motor regardless (its 40ish years old) and I will replace the capacitors just to change them out, but I believe I should remove that 2nd capacitor from the fan. Am I correct in thinking that contributed to killing the motor?

Comment: It's not completely clear how the wiring is arranged - a photo or a diagram would help. Also, there may be a label on the motor which shows its wire colors and their intended connections. Capacitors can be wired in parallel (equivalent capacitance is the sum of the individual capacitors) but it sounds like that's not what's going on here. It's also not clear what a "heat pump that .. isn't spinning" means. Maybe you mean it's the condenser fan that is noisy and not spinning?